# How can I count numbers of movies for each Genre using R?

Tags: r

I have an excel with values:

| Genre | Name | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fantasy | Lord of the Rings | 2003 |
| Action | Inception | 2010 |
| Sci-fi | Interstellar | 2015 |
| Comics | Avengers | 2010 |
| Action | Jumanji | 2019 |

How can I calculate quantity of movies grouped by each genre using R?

Answer (score 0):

You may just use `table` like `table(df$Genre)`